# Yet Another Conditional Operator Nesting Question

Tags: c, conditional-operator

As per C precedence tables, the ternary conditional operator has right-to-left 
associativity.

So, is it directly convertible to the equivalent if-else ladder?

For example, can:

```
x?y?z:u:v;
```

be interpreted as:

```
if(x)
{
   if(y)
   { z; }
   else
   { u; }
}
else
{ v; }
```

by matching an else (`:`) with the closest unpaired if (`?`)? Or does right-to-left associativity imply some other arrangement?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The example you gave could only be interpreted in one way (like the if statements you gave), whether the ternary operator had right-to-left or left-to-right associativity.

Where the right-to-left associativity matters is when you have:

```
x = a ? b : c ? d : e;
```

Which is interpreted as: `x = a ? b : (c ? d : e)`, not as `x = (a ? b : c) ? d : e`.

To give a more realistic example:

```
int getSign(int x) {
    return x < 0 ? -1 :
           x > 0 ?  1 :
                    0;
}
```

This is identical to the (probably more readable) if / else-if statements:

```
int getSign(int x) {
    if (x < 0)
         return -1;
    else if (x > 0)
         return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your assumption is correct; however, it is often wise to add in parentheses for readability, e.g.:

```
x ? ( y ? z : u ) : v
```

Comment: +1 although I would say it is even wiser *not* to nest conditional operators ever in real production code :-)

Comment: I think "not using" is overrated. Replace `?` with `then` and `:` with `else`, and you have perfectly valid selection syntax in a number of languages. I write nested conditionals like this all the time, making sure each new ? and : appears on a new line, with the correct indentation. It's as readable as any if/else blocks.

Comment: @Pétet: In the few cases where the conditional operator is the only tool that can accomplish the job (macros and special usage taking advantage of its strange and wonderful type conversion properties), nesting them is often necessary. :-)

Comment: I've occasionally had to maintain code written by people whose goal in life seemed to be accomplishing every task using as little code as possible. I don't mean to knock interjay--it's a perfectly valid question; I've simply found much more value in expressive, readable, code than in slightly decreased source code file sizes.

Comment: On the other hand, if you come from a functional background where you can express a selection that returns a value more easily, you'll prefer this solution. The alternative is often to create a mutable variable (not desirable to functional programmers), just so you can assign a different result from each part of an if/else block. The ?: syntax is the only way of achieving the same expressiveness in C and other languages. It's not all about reducing lines of code. Readability is subjective anyhow.

Comment: @Sparkie, are you sure that (at least the majority of) your coworkers agree with you on this? :-)